# Place text just above and below x axis of stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to place two words (Increasing / Decreasing) to the left of the bar written vertically just above and below the x-axis. I'm trying `annotate` but with not much luck. The text overlaps and isn't placed correctly in all cases.

What is the best way to place the text just above and below the light grey x-axis with enough room to display the word. The possible positive values range from 0 to 50 and negative from 0 to -50.

There are 3 tests below the R script.

```
library("tidyverse")

red <- "#CD5C5C"
gold <- "#FCB700"
lt_grey <- "#D8D8D8"
dark_grey <- "#525250"
axis_text_size <- 16

df <- tibble(
  type = c("up", "down"),
  term = c("1yr", "1yr"),
  value = c(3, -6),
  display_value = c(3, 6),
  vjust = c(-0.3, 1.2),
  bar_num_col = c("#FCB700", "#C8F5C0")
)

# Stacked bar plot
ggplot(df, aes(fill = type, y = value, x = term)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(red, gold)) +
  labs(title = "Title") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = axis_text_size),
    axis.text.y =  element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size = 0.2, linetype = 'solid',
                                      colour = "#696969"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = dark_grey),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(term, label = display_value,  vjust = vjust, color = type), size = 8) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(red, gold)) +
  
  # Add horizontal line
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1.5, colour = lt_grey) +
  
  # Expand grey area above and below ends of bars to make room for the numbers. (bottom, top)
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.1))) +

  annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = 0.3, label= "bold(Increases)",
           col = gold, size = 8, angle = 90, parse = TRUE) +

  annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = -0.31, label= "bold(Decreases)",
           col = red, size = 8, angle = 90, parse = TRUE)


# Tests -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Test 1
df$value <- c(0, 0)  
df$display_value <- c(0, 0)

# Test 2
df$value <- c(2, -5)  
df$display_value = c(2, 5)

# Test 3
df$value <- c(2, -50)  
df$display_value = c(2, 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<YOUR CODE> +
annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = 0.1, vjust = 1, hjust = 0, label= "bold(Increases)",
           col = gold, size = 7, angle = 90, parse = TRUE) +
annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = -0.1, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, label= "bold(Decreases)",
           col = red, size = 7, angle = 90, parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

The text will take up different amounts of chart space depending on the output dimensions and text size; if you want more predictability while outputting in different sizes, you might look at the `ggtext` package and define the annotations to fill boxes whose dimensions are defined in chart space.